# Accidentally removed myself as administrator on Facebook business page, now can't edit it

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I accidentally removed myself as administrator on my Facebook business page and now I can't edit it.

The pages, at "golfbookie", now has no administrator and is inaccessible by me, its creator.

How do I fix it so I can edit it, or at least reinstate myself as the admin?

I've had no response from Facebook.

Comment: Its a well-known great flaw of Facebook...

Answer (score 1):

I am sure [Facebook Support](http://www.facebook.com/help/) could help you out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but Facebook Support will NOT help you out. I had the same problem. Facebook has EXTREMELY poor support.